# Como fazer cálculo da distância em menos linhas?

Tags: c, matemática

Tenho esse exercício sobre C para calcular a distância entre dois pontos usando `structs`, mas ele repete muito o código do ponto, para `x` e `y`, como fazer em menos linhas ou usar *array*?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} ponto;
int main() {

    ponto p1;
    printf("Digite o ponto p1(X): ");
    scanf("%d", &p1.x);

    printf("Digite o ponto p1(Y): ");
    scanf("%d", &p1.y);

    ponto p2;
    printf("Digite o ponto p2(X): ");
    scanf("%d", &p2.x);

    printf("Digite o ponto p2(Y): ");
    scanf("%d", &p2.y);

    /*Formula para calcular distancia entre dois pontos
     * d = sqrt((p2 x - p1 x)² + (p2 y - p1 y)²)
     */

     float distancia = sqrt((pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2)) + ((pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2))));
     printf("Resultado: %.2f", distancia);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu poderia fazer, mas vou apenas te dar alguns caminhos. Quando um código se repete muito alguma coisa está errada, ou o código poderia ser melhorado, esse é o seu caso. Tente separar a leitura de dados, crie um método onde você envie a struct por referência, bole como você exibirá o texto para o usuário é bem fácil e você consegue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sem fazer coisas muito malucas e prejudicar a legibilidade, tem bem pouca coisa que pode ser feita. Dá para declarar as duas variáveis na mesma linha, reduzir as linhas em branco e comentários desnecessários, eliminar o `#include` sem uso e eliminar a variável que não é necessária, além de tirar os parênteses desnecessários.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} ponto;
int main() {
    ponto p1, p2;
    printf("Digite o ponto p1(X): ");
    scanf("%d", &p1.x);
    printf("Digite o ponto p1(Y): ");
    scanf("%d", &p1.y);
    printf("Digite o ponto p2(X): ");
    scanf("%d", &p2.x);
    printf("Digite o ponto p2(Y): ");
    scanf("%d", &p2.y);
    printf("Resultado: %.2f", sqrt(pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + (pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2))));
}
```

Fora isto não sei se deseja mudar a estrutura do código. Não sei quais o requisitos. É possível fazer um laço para reduzir ainda mais. É possível criar uma função para lidar com o carregamento dos dois pontos.

Você pode reduzir o tamanho do código e aumentar sua complexidade. Compensa? Está preparado para lidar com esta complexidade?

Se quer, como mostra nos comentários abaixo, então pode fazer desta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} ponto;
int quadradoPontos(int p1, int p2) {
    return pow(p2 - p1, 2);
}
void lePonto(char nome, char coordenada, ponto *p) {
    printf("\nDigite o ponto p%c(%c): ", nome, coordenada);
    if (coordenada == 'X') {
        scanf("%d", &p->x);
    } else {
        scanf("%d", &p->y);
    }
}
int main() {
    ponto p1, p2;
    lePonto('1', 'X', &p1);
    lePonto('1', 'Y', &p1);
    lePonto('2', 'X', &p2);
    lePonto('2', 'Y', &p2);
    printf("\nResultado: %.2f", sqrt(quadradoPontos(p1.x, p2.x) + quadradoPontos(p1.y, p2.y)));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/emXNfO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/coezpqxy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Pythagoras.c).

Ficou mais simples? Não. Ficou mais curto? Não. Se era um exercício sobre criar uma função, ok. Mas aí deveria estar na pergunta. Deveria postar como tinha tentado fazer a função, que problemas estava tendo com ela. A pergunta seria outra.

Obviamente se passar argumentos errados para a função, vai dar tudo errado. Qual a vantagem de fazer isto senão for um exemplo de criação de função? Nenhuma. Mesmo que seja um exemplo de função, tem exemplos melhores, este só ensina aumentar a complexidade e deixar o código menos robusto. Tudo isto porque não tinha repetição de código algum. Tinha uma aparência de repetição, mas não repetição de fato. O que foi feito não tem nada a ver com [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), que seria algo efeito, muito pelo contrário.

Tive que criar 3 variáveis extras e 2 desvios de fluxo, um deles remoto ao código principal, que dificulta o acompanhamento do fluxo, e tive que parametrizar algo que não precisava. Isto se chama complexidade.

Poderia fazer de formas diferentes, poderia ter duas ou 4 funções para escrever na tela e pedir dados. Ajudaria em alguma coisa? Diminuiria a complexidade, mas aumentaria a "repetição". A função que calcula o quadrado poderia eliminar um pouco da "repetição" e poderia passar os pontos ao e resolver lá dentro da função qual coordenada usar. Isto ficar mais complexo, sem necessidade, ganho discutível (na verdade para os programadores experientes não há discussão de qual é pior).

Repense seu conceito de repetição, a legibilidade deve vir em primeiro lugar: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Claro que sim, não aumentará a complexidade e você pode reutilizar o código. Princípio da OO.

Comment: Primeiro: Ahã, OO? Do que está falando? Orientação a objeto em C? OO em um exemplo simples de um cálculo bobo que é um exercício? Eu imaginava algumas maluquices, mas propor OO em um código assim é uma que eu jamais imaginaria que alguém proporia. Mas um simples laço tornaria o código mais complexo. Teria que usar variáveis extras, controlar o fluxo, para ganhar poucas linhas. Na verdade, eu acho que nem ganharia linhas, se bobear ficaria maior. Antes de se deslumbrar em OO comece entender o que é complexidade. Não é uma questão de opinião. Há definição formal sobre isto.

Comment: Eu queria usar uma função, declarei assim: void ler(ponto *p) { scanf("%d", p->x), mas da um erro.

Comment: @user46084 A pergunta é `Como fazer em menos linhas?`. Nela não se fala em função. Se ainda quiser usar uma função, provavelmente ficará com mais linhas. Isto sequer está no código postado. Você tem que escrever na pergunta o que realmente quer, eu respondi o que está escrito nela. Se queria outra coisa, a pergunta deve ser fechada por não estar clara.

Comment: Deu certo não estava usando esse & na função, mas fica mais legível

Comment: Mas, você só não removeu os comentários e a variável distancia?, poderia ser usando função.

Comment: @user46084 sim, poderia, mas sua pergunta não fala em nada disso. Eu vou colocar na resposta como quer, mas estou indo além do que a pergunta faz.

Comment: +1.  Boa demonstração (e explicação) de um caso típico em que era melhor deixar tudo como estava, que não tinha problema nenhum.

Comment: Esse monte de printf e scanf deixa o código muito repetidoooooo.

Comment: @user46084 Não tem nenhum repetição. Tenho a impressão que você tem um TOC pior que o meu :) . Cada linha é semanticamente diferente da outra. Se um dia vier a se tornar programador, vai entender que o primeiro código é bem melhor. Repetição só corre quando todos os *tokens* são iguais, não é o caso. Em função disto, tive que criar vários artifícios para resolver esta irregularidade. Tem situações que compensa fazer isto, esta não é uma delas. Note que o código de baixo está cheio de repetição também, segundo o seu critério. Tente resolver isto.

Comment: @user46084 pra programar é melhor focar mais na técnica do que nessas "emoções" estéticas. Estética no código é igual design: é valiosa, mas só presta se a forma se aliar à função.

Comment: Mas é porque o exercício é muito simples

Comment: @user46084 ele era para ser muito simples, ficou complexo. E justamente por ser algo muito simples não deveria complicar. Se tivesse um motivo real pra fazer tudo isto, ok, sem problemas, mas não tem. Quem complica o simples, destrói o complicado.

Answer (score 2):

Só para complementar a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128834/69296), você pode utilizar a função `hypot`, definida (também) no cabeçalho `math.h`.

[Veja a documentação.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot)

Essa função basicamente retorna a raiz quadrada da soma dos quadrados dos dois números fornecidos. Em outras palavras, devolve a hipotenusa (***hypot**enuse*) do triângulo retângulo.

Veja, ao invés de:

```c
sqrt(pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + (pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2)))
```

Pode fazer:

```c
hypot(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
```

Assim:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} ponto;

int main() {
  ponto p1, p2;
  printf("Digite o ponto p1(X): ");
  scanf("%d", &p1.x);
  printf("Digite o ponto p1(Y): ");
  scanf("%d", &p1.y);
  printf("Digite o ponto p2(X): ");
  scanf("%d", &p2.x);
  printf("Digite o ponto p2(Y): ");
  scanf("%d", &p2.y);

  printf("Resultado: %.2f\n", hypot(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y));
}
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/Yj47VQ)</sup>